# Legal penalties for fraudulent visa applications in Belgian law

Tags: schengen, belgium, fraud

I attempted to search the [1981 decree](https://dofi.ibz.be/en/themes/propos/legislation) regulating immigration matters to Belgium to find the legal consequences of a fraudulent visa application, but I was not successful.

What are the legal penalties for committing consular fraud, such as false testimony, false documentation, false passport, etc., whether it is direct or indirect, when applying for a visa to enter Belgium?

Additionally, how long will the person be banned from entering the Schengen zone? I would like to compare this to the English speaking countries (US, UK, etc.), where the ban could range from 10 years to indefinitely.

Comment: Welcome to our forum! Your specific question is probably a better fit for law.exchange.com where people with a legal background can look a it.

Comment: Note: it is a very bad crime, so you probably get a ban, but also very probably your future visa applications will not be accepted also after the expiration of the ban (and in many other countries as well). (this is about travel part). Then law stack exchange may give you more details. But it is a crime, and very probably a crime also in your country (forging official documents), so Belgium may ask your country to take further actions.